Why do I get DGNSS on my ublox GNSS receiver
We built a measurement system that is operated on cars in Germany. Among other things that measurements system includes a u-blox ZED-F9P GNSS receiver on a Sparkfun board and a Raspberry Pi. The two are connected via UART. The GNSS messages are logged with Python. The measurement system isn't connected to the phone network - there is no modem or SIM in there.
Roughly half the time we get NMEA messages without differential corrections like this:
1720048649.4872622, "$GNRMC,135904.00,A,5051.85346,N,01026.42880,E,8.269,140.82,230724,,,A,V*04

And half the time we do have differential corrections (this worked out of the box):
$GNRMC,115316.00,A,5051.49037,N,01024.93509,E,0.012,,230724,,,D,V*1A

According to the receiver's protocol manual (page 9) the letter before the last comma indicates the position fix flag:

A means Autonomous GNSS fix (no DGNSS)
D means Differential GNSS fix

I would like to know how the DGNSS correction data is transferred to our receiver.
Many Google searches later, I can find that SAPOS provides free DGNSS data via NTRIP (requires internet) and that WSV provides DGNSS via MF radio. The datasheet of the GNSS receiver doesn't mention anything about internet or a phone connection and afaik MF radio antennas are huge.
So it doesn't seem to be either of those.
I wonder what kind of receiver for correction data is in the ZED-F9P. I'm only aware that it can receive SBAS but maybe I'm missing something.
We also have EGNOS SBAS in Europe that sends some corrections from the geostationary satellites which the ZED-F9P can receive but I'm not sure if that counts as DGNSS (in the data sheet SBAS is a different heading before DGNSS).
What infrastructure provides that Differential GNSS fix to our receivers half the time?

What can I do to make the question more focused? It clearly asks only one question: Where does the differential correction signal come from? The linked datasheet of the receiver, description of what it is (and is not) connected to and geographical location should be enough to answer that question.

The Tour calls for One question per Question. You could make this more focused by only using one question mark.

@Vince I've rephrased. The question was clear from the title and the equivalent question at the very end. I do not think there's a policy on SE to avoid sub-questions that directly serve to answer the main question. In any case, I've removed a few question marks to make it clearer to read.

The NMEA RMC sentence doesn't provide a way to distinguish between NTRIP-corrected and SBAS-corrected, these are both regarded as DGNSS and will have "D" in the RMC Mode indicator field.  If you are not supplying NTRIP data to the GNSS receiver, RMC sentence Mode Indicator of "D" is almost certainly because your receiver is tracking an SBAS satellite and using SBAS corrections (EGNOS in Europe, WAAS in USA, etc.)
I have seen RMC Mode Indicator of "D" when using M8-T and earlier uBlox receivers and receiving SBAS corrections from the Australia / NZ SouthPAN SBAS satellite.  I've also seen RMC Mode Indicator of "D" when supplying RTCM 2.x DGPS corrections via NTRIP from a local base station.

Are you saying the "D" must indicate that the correction data is coming from EGNOS OS? Is that the only possibility? So the "this is" in your answer refers to SBAS?

@Joooeey - I've edited my answer to clarify.  If you are not supplying correction data via Internet or radio or other complicated channel, the "D" can only be because the receiver is using SBAS corrections.
